# Expected Operating temperature for a FX-8350 with stock cooler

Tags: cpu, temperature

I've looked and looked and haven't been able to find good information one way or another. Nothing published by AMD nor information in other forums that match my criteria (non-OC, stock cooler).

I just need to know what is the expected operating temperature for a non-overclocked FX-8350 with the stock cooler/fan?

I'd prefer a good temp. range for idle and a good temp. range under load. If there is a known max, that'd be great too.

Right now, I'm seeing a idle temp of about 32c. Under load, it went up to 66c before I stopped Prime95.

Edit: Under load in BF3, the CPU got to 57c.

Comment: If it matters, it just dropped to 31c.

Comment: SuperUser mods are close happy compared to StackOverflow. They're really runing this. I'm using it less and less because my real, valid questions keep getting closed. I'd like to know what type of question IS valid for SU? Cause nothing seems to be....

Comment: This question is not being close voted by mods, it's voted upon by users of this site, your question is too localized because idle and maximum temperatures differ from person to person, they depend on ambient temperatures, airflow of your case, and if you did a bad thermal job, you can expect high temperatures. Read the [faq](http://superuser.com/faq#dontask)

Comment: I don't see any mods closing this - I see regular users who feel this is too localised. The temperatures you're seeing look *perfectly normal*, and actually on the cool side depending on what your room temperature is. Please note the difference between the Mods, and higher rep users as well - and that should a good question be closed, you can feel free to ask on meta to have it reopened.

Answer (score 2):

Your mileage will vary. A cooler can only cool the CPU to whatever the ambient room temperature is, at best. My CPU at home is a Phenom II and it runs OC'd @4Ghz and typically is in the mid-high 50's. 32c is quite good i'd say. The thermal max (where it shuts down to avoid damage) Your cpu appears to be rated up to around 60c before issues happen. I'd say you have nothing to worry about.

Prime95 is intended to generate a TON of heat, so while it's a great test for load-testing, its not a representation of what you'd expect in "real life" use.

Comment: The max temp is 90 not 60

Comment: @HackToHell I don't think that is accurate. A CPU running at 90c is crazy hot, and surely would damage the mobo (socket mainly) if left at that temp for long. 60-62c is generally what AMD has always considered "safe" for their cpus, especially those in the FX lineup which are designed for overclocking, etc. I cannot find an official source from AMD, and of course there is mixed info on the web, but I would never go above 60-62c for long, otherwise it's time to get a new cooler. Check out: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=35-181-031&Tpk=35-181-031 Great cooler for cheap.

Comment: @HackToHell, remember that this is an AMD processor. Different processor makes -- and families, have different tolerances.

Comment: @SnakeDoc It's not 90 but 70, AMD's FX series have a different way of measuring temperatures and the temperature depiction is not accurate, the actual temperatures can vary by +-15 C. The people at OC.net asked AMD about the maximum temperature and `As long as your core temperature has not exceeded the high side of the 60 degree mark for extended periods of time you should be ok. 62 degrees holds a generous safety net to begin with.
`

Comment: @HackToHell thanks for following up on that. Seems the 60-62 range is still what would be considered "safe". Agreed on the measurement of actual temperature, intel/amd have always had different ways of measuring the temps, some being more accurate than others. It comes down to what you classify as "core temp" really.

Answer (score 1):

just got my FX8350 with the stock cooler...
ASrock 960GM U3S3 FX
G skill Ripjaws 16GB 1866

during video editing and light gaming simultaneously i get up to 60 degrees celcius,
am going to buy new power supply PSU and more chasis fans...
MOBO is 41 degrees or so